# Como fazer um filtro por data no Django

Tags: django, data, view, filtro

Preciso fazer uma filtro na views no qual me traga a data dos últimos 30 dias.
E não sei ao certo como fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from django.views import generic

class SuaListView(generic.ListView):

    queryset = Foo.objects.filter(creation_date__gte=datetime.today()-timedelta(days=30))
    context_object_name = 'foo'
    template_name = 'your_template.html'
```

Isto retornará todos os resultados dos últimos 30 dias em uma ListView.